# Pass parameter from form to Controller Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to understand how to pass parameters via URL in Laravel.

In my case I've a home page (/) (HomeController@get__home and view home) that contains n data get from a database table.
The user can select one of them and go to the next page.

The second url page is /{param from first page}/login

The field {param from first page} comes from (of course) first page and depends on which record was selected.

I've read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-model-binding), but I think I'm out of the way.

I can not find a way to pass the parameter to the url.

In my Route.php:

```
Route::get("/", "HomeController@home");
Route::get("/{position}/login", "LoginController@login");
```

and in Controllers:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function home(){

      $foos = Foo::all();

      return view('home')->with('foos',$foos);
    }
}

class LoginController extends Controller
{
  public function login(Foo $foo)
  {
    return view('login');
  }
}
```

and in home.blade.php

```
<form class="" action="{{action(LoginController@login)}}" method="post">
...
```

Answer (score 9):

Since you're using a form with post method, you should define the route like this:

```
Route::post("/login", "LoginController@login");
```

And then call it in the form action:

```
<form action="{{action('LoginController@login')}}" method="post">
    <select name="position">
        <option value="1">Position 1</option>
        <option value="2">Position 2</option>
    </select>
...
```

Then, in the controller, you can get the option in the request:

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $position = $request->position;
        return view('login');
    }
}
```